# Castle Windsor: Inject array of services from xml config

Tags: xml, arrays, castle-windsor, castle, inject

I'm having problems injecting an array of services via Castle Windsor with xml configuration. I've followed [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/InversionOfControlAndDependencyInjectionWithCastleWindsorContainerPart2.aspx) link which explains it quite well, but somehow it doesn't work for me. Here's the code I'm using:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromAppConfig());

        var consumer = container.Resolve<Consumer>();
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(IFoo[] foos)
    {
        foreach (IFoo foo in foos)
            foo.Foo();
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public void Foo() { }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public void Foo() { }
}
```

And here's the app.config:

```
<castle>
  <components>
     <component id="Foo1" service="Test.IFoo, Test" type="Test.Foo1, Test" />
     <component id="Foo2" service="Test.IFoo, Test" type="Test.Foo2, Test" />

     <component id="Consumer" service="Test.Consumer, Test">
        <parameters>
           <foos>
              <array>
                 <item>${Foo1}</item>
                 <item>${Foo2}</item>
              </array>
           </foos>
        </parameters>
     </component>
  </components>
</castle>
```

Strangely, the error I'm getting is the following:

```
Can't create component 'Test.Consumer' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
'Test.Consumer' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'Test.IFoo[]' which was not registered.
```

Why does it expect IFoo[] as a service? Does that make any sense? Or maybe the link I'm referring to doesn't work any longer with the current version of Windsor (I'm on 3.1.0)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To once again answer my own question (sorry ;-):

Turned out that the solution is quite simple - once you know. Adding an ArrayResolver as a subresolver not only makes this working:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));
        container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromAppConfig());

        var consumer = container.Resolve<Consumer>();
    }
```

But even simplyfies configuration, as you don't have to setup the instances:

```
  <configuration>
     <configSections>
        <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
     </configSections>
     <castle>
        <components>
           <component id="Foo1" service="Test.IFoo, Test" type="Test.Foo1, Test" />
           <component id="Foo2" service="Test.IFoo, Test" type="Test.Foo2, Test" />
           <component id="Consumer" service="Test.Consumer, Test"/>
        </components>
     </castle>
  </configuration>
```

As always it turns out that Castle Windsor is great, but documentation is not and the many different versions you'll find examples for in the web won't make it easier...